# angularjs service factory function is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, factory

I am calling a service function and within the processed results I am calling another service function.  The first (outter) works, processes the results, and depending on the results, and then calls a second service function.  However, the second service function is returning an error `clientService.getClient(...).then is not a function`.   Its the same service factory and the function setups and calls are identical.

```
.factory("clientService", function($http,$q) {
 
  function getDataSet(typeID) {
    // retrieve full data client list from server
  }

  function getClient(id,typeID) {
    // return client data from already retrieved full client list
  }

  return  {
    getDataSet: function(typeID) {
      return getDataSet(typeID) ;
    },
    getClient: function(id,typeID) {
      return getClient(id,typeID) ;
    }
  }
})
```

...and in my controller I am calling

```
clientService.getDataSet(2)   // <-- works fine
.then(function(response) {
  if (response.list != null) {
    $scope.clientsList = response.list ;  // <-- list retrieved successfully
    if ($stateParams.openID) {
      clientService.getClient($stateParams.openID,2)  // <-- Error: "clientService.getClient(...).then is not a function"
      .then(function(clientResponse) {
        // process client data
       }) ;
    }
  } else {
    logResponse("Client list was is empty") ;
  }
}) ;
```

I am confused by this one.

Comment: well, in your code, there is no `.then()` from getClient, as no promise is being returned....

Comment: @kinglist - and you were correct!  `getClient` is not a promise...its just a regular function that needs to be called as `var cInfo = clubService.getClient($stateParams.openID,2) ; `  I over looked that thinking the function was set as a promise.